# How To Initialize and Fill 2D Array of Bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-view

I want to initialize and display a four by four grid of circles. I'm recieving two errors:

1 is actually a warning: The static method createBitmap  from type bitmap should be accessed in a static way.

1 error: The constructor Bitmap() is not visible.

Below is my code.

```
package com.example.dcubebluetooth;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class LEDView extends View{

    Paint background = new Paint();
    Paint black = new Paint();
    Paint red = new Paint();
    int numRows = 4;
    int numCols = 4;
    Bitmap[][] leds = new Bitmap[numRows][numCols];
    Canvas ledDrawer = new Canvas();

    public LEDView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        background.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        black.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        red.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        for(int y=0; y<numCols; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<numRows; x++){
                Bitmap map =  Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.RGB_565); //Error here
                leds[x][y] = map;
                ledDrawer.setBitmap(leds[x][y]);
                ledDrawer.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, black);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPaint(background);
        for(int y=0; y<numCols; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<numRows; x++){
                canvas.drawBitmap(leds[x][y], x*100, y*100, null);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

I did a previous project in which I did this and it gave me no errors or warnings:

```
//Instance variable
Bitmap touchPad; 

//In constructor
touchPad = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, (int) (screenHeight*0.75), Config.RGB_565);
```

What is the difference between the two?

Extra information: The four by four grid will represent a layer of LEDs connected to my microcontroller. I'm gonna have four other buttons to the side to change between layers and some more arrays to store current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any error or warning on this code! (i tested here)

You are probably seeing old warnings/errors from lint, try to clean them: **Right click on the project > Android Tools > Clear Lint Markers**

This warning/error happens when you are calling createBitmap from a Bitmap instance, example:

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();
    bmp.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.RGB_565);
```